# Distinctions between Universal Generalization, Existential Instantiation, and Introduction Rule of Implication using an example claim

Tags: logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

From recent dives throughout these tags, I have learned that there are several different flavors of deductive reasoning (Hilbert, Genzten...natural deduction, sequent calculus...etc). This has made it a bit difficult to pick up on a single interpretation of how exactly Universal Generalization ("$\forall \text{I}$")$^1$, Existential Instantiation ("$\exists \text{E}$")$^2$, and Introduction Rule of Implication ("$\rightarrow \text{ I }$") $^3$  are **different** in their formal implementations.

Consider the following claim (which requires the the individual to carry out *all* of the three aforementioned inference rules):

$$\forall m \in \mathbb{Z} : \left( \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k+1 = m \right) \rightarrow \left( \exists k' \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k'+1 = m^2 \right)$$

In English: "For any odd number $m$, it's square is also odd".

For convenience let's have: $$\varphi(m):=\left( \exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k+1 = m \right) \rightarrow \left( \exists k' \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k'+1 = m^2 \right)$$

By convention, the above statement is equivalent to the following:

$$\forall m \left[m \in \mathbb Z \rightarrow \varphi(m) \right]$$

In the following paragraphs, I will go through my understandings of this proof from purely the deductive argument side of things and sprinkle in the occasional explicit question, marked with a colored dagger ($\color{red}{\dagger}$). Any added commentary is greatly appreciated.

---

As is typical with conditional based proofs, we say, "Assume $m^* \in \mathbb Z$". This is an application of ($\rightarrow \text{ I }$), and it establishes two things: 1) $m^*$ is now an **unbound** symbol representing something and 2) $m^*$ has the property that it is an integer.

Our goal is to then show that $\varphi(m^*)$ is true. Of note, $\varphi(m^*)$ is *itself* a conditional, and therefore we assume the antecedent of $\varphi(m^*)$, which is another invocation of ($\rightarrow \text{ I }$). We say, "Assume $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k+1 = m^*$." This introduces another variable $k$, but I believe it is relevant to state that this new variable $k$ is **bound**, and therefore (I think) is not *really* a new variable in the sense that $m^*$ was ($\color{red}{\dagger}$).

> As an aside, when I see existential claims, I think of sets whose elements satisfy the claim. For example, in the case of "$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k+1 = m^*$", I think of the following set, which is non-empty by assumption:  $S=\{k \in \mathbb Z \ |\  2k+1=m^*\}$. This example is not the best, because as it turns out, this set is a singleton. However, one can easily envision a scenario where the set described by the existential claim is not-finite (i.e. countably or uncountably infinite)...in which case, it is not apparent to me *at all* why I am given license to "reach into this set" and pull an object out for the purpose of argument, as we will see next ($\color{red}{\dagger}$).

Now, by ($\exists E$), we say, "Choose a $k^* \in S$". We have just introduced a new symbol $k^*$ into our argument. Importantly, this symbol is unbounded. By definition of $S$, this means that $2k^*+1=m^*$.

Algebraic manipulation will subsequently reveal that:

\begin{align}
(m^*)^2&=(2k^*+1)^2 \\
&=4(k^*)^2+4k^*+1 \\
&=2\left[(2k^*)^2+2k^* \right] +1 \\
\end{align}

It  is easy to show that $(2k^*)^2+2k^*$ is itself an integer and satisfies the necessary property specified by the consequent. One then employs existential generalization to conclude $\exists k' \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k'+1 = (m^*)^2$.

Up to this point, we have shown that $m^* \in \mathbb Z \rightarrow \varphi(m^*)$. Taken from another post, here is the definition of ($\forall \text{ I }$)

> If $P(c)$ must be true, *and we have assumed nothing about $c$*, then $\forall x P(x)$ is true.

In order to replicate the described form above, I suppose it is reasonable to collapse $m^* \in \mathbb Z \rightarrow \varphi(m^*)$ into a new formula $\psi(m^*):= m^* \in \mathbb Z \rightarrow \varphi(m^*)$. In which case, I would say that I proved $\psi(m^*)$. **However**, I most definitely **did** assume something about $m^*$. In fact, I assumed several things. Firstly, I assumed it is an integer. Secondly, I assumed that it satisfied that statement $\exists k \in \mathbb Z: 2k+1=m^*$. It seems to me that I have violated the conditions that would otherwise let me claim $\forall m \psi(m)$! ($\color{red}{\dagger}$)

The only thing I can think to do is create a new set $T = \{m \in \mathbb Z \ | \  \exists k \in \mathbb Z: 2k+1=m \}$. This set $T$ effectively represents the assumptions I have made. Then, I would argue I could claim: $\psi(m^*) \vdash \forall m \in T \left[\psi(m) \right]$.

Deconstructing what $\forall m \in T \left[\psi(m) \right]$ means, we effectively have the form:

$\forall m \left [ A \land B \rightarrow \left(A \rightarrow \left(B \rightarrow C \right) \right) \right]$, which I am relieved to find out is equivalent to simply $\forall m \left [A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C) \right]$...i.e. $\forall m \psi(m)$.

I have never seen the above work carried out in any post/article/book, perhaps because, in the end, it does not matter. If I could have confirmation that this is correct thinking, I would greatly appreciate it ($\color{red}{\dagger}$).

---

Comment: "I most definitely did assume something about m∗. In fact, I assumed several things" NO; you have derived a formula $\psi(m)$ and there are no assumptions left regarding $m$. Thus, you can correctly us $(\forall \text I)$ to conclude with $\forall x \psi (x)$.

Comment: There is an "intuitive" difference between: "Socrates is a philosopher, therefore everyone is a philosopher" and "let John Doe a human whatever; if John Doe is a philosopher, then every human is a philosopher". This intuitive difference must be formalized some way: the restriction on Gen rule is one of the way.

Comment: There are many many posts on this subject in MSE. You can try to find them and see how the above rules work starting with simple example. See e.g [When are we allowed to use the ∃ elimination rule in first-order natural deduction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229838/when-are-we-allowed-to-use-the-exists-elimination-rule-in-first-order-natural) and [Universal Generalisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914609/universal-generalisation-forall-i)

Comment: and [Universal/Existential Generalizations and Specifications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848340/what-set-of-formal-rules-can-we-use-to-safely-apply-universal-existential-genera) and [Formal structure of a proof with the goal ∃xP(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802684/formal-structure-of-a-proof-with-the-goal-exists-x-px) and [Restrictions on the use of universal generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969231/restrictions-on-the-use-of-universal-generalization).

Comment: Having said that, your proof is correct. In order to prove: $\forall m (\text {Even}(m) \to \text {Even}(m^2))$, we have to prove $(\text {Even}(m) \to \text {Even}(m^2))$for an $m$ whatever and then generalize it using $(\forall \text I)$.

Comment: Thus, the "core" of the proof is a Conditional Proof: assume the antecedent, use $(\exists \text E)$ with a $k$ new, derive the consequent using $(\exists \text I)$ where $k$ does not occur and thus you are allowed to close the $(\exists \text E)$ sub-proof. Now discharge the assumption $(\text {Even}(m))$ with $(\to \text I)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, Mauro. There is one point that I would like clarification on: I believe I have been conflating "**assumption**" with "**antecedent**". In your first comment, you claim, *"...you have derived a formula $\psi(m^*)$ and there are no assumptions left regarding $m^*$"*. When analyzing my derivation for $\psi(m^*)$, *here* is what I believe I carried out:$$ m^* \in \mathbb Z, \exists k : 2k+1=m^* \vdash \exists k'\in \mathbb Z : 2k'+1=(m^*)^2 $$

Comment: At this point, the items to the **left** of "$\vdash$" are **assumptions**. However, when I subsequently **discharge** these assumptions, I generate the following syntax:

$$\vdash \left (m^* \in \mathbb Z \ \land \ \exists k : 2k+1=m^* \right) \rightarrow k'\in \mathbb Z : 2k'+1=(m^*)^2$$

At this point, "$m^* \in \mathbb Z$" and "$\exists k : 2k+1=m^*$" are **no longer** assumptions. They are **antecedents** to a conditional. Note that the above form is equivalent to:

Comment: $$\vdash m^* \in \mathbb Z \rightarrow \left[\exists k : 2k+1=m^* \rightarrow \exists k'\in \mathbb Z : 2k'+1=(m^*)^2 \right]$$

i.e. we have:

$$\vdash \psi(m^*)$$

So when you say *"...there are no assumptions left regarding $m^*$*, you are effectively stating that there are no formulas involving $m^*$ **to the left of $\vdash$** in the final statement of "$\vdash \psi(m^*)$". Is that correct?

Comment: Correct; when you have $\vdash \psi(m)$ i.e. $\vdash m∈ \mathbb Z → \varphi(m)$ there are no assumptions left, i.e. no formulas with $m$ (because no formulas at all, except the arithmetical axioms :-)) at the left of $\vdash$. Thus, apply **Generalization (meta-)thorem**: if $\vdash \alpha$, then $\vdash \forall x \alpha$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you for all of the the effort in your follow ups (as well as post recommendations) - it is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome :-)